# A quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $AB = 10$ , $BC = 6$ , $CD = 8$ and $DA = 2$ has diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meeting at $O$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, problem-solving, polygons

> A quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $AB = 10$ , $BC = 6$ , $CD = 8$ and $DA = 2$ has diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meeting at $O$, such that $\angle COB = 45^\circ$. Find the area of $ABCD$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

The only thing missing to find the area is one of the diagonals, and I can find the area easily by Heron's Formula. Also I thought that since some angles are there, I might have to use trigonometry, and I tried but without success.

We have that $\angle DOC = \angle AOB = 135^\circ$ . I know that the area of a triangle can be found from the formula :- $$\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}ab\sin \gamma$$

Where $\gamma$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$, but I cannot use it sadly as I don't know any of the lengths of $AO$ , $BO$ , $CO$ and $DO$. Next I thought of the formula :-
$$\rightarrow \frac{a}{\sin a} = \frac{b}{\sin b} = \frac{c}{\sin c}$$

But this dosen't work here either due to the same reason.

I think that Law of Cosines might work, but I am actually new to Trigonometry and not sure if it will really work or not, and then I have to consider $4$ equations for $4$ sides, which will be complicated.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

**Note**:- Solutions without Trigonometry and mostly welcome. I hate using Trigonometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$[ABCD] = \dfrac{1}{2} AC  \cdot BD \cdot \sin 45$$

> $$[BAD] = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot OA \sin 45 \cdot BD$$
> $$[BCD] = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot OC \sin 45 \cdot BD$$

**Hint 2 :**
Use cosine-rule in all four small triangles and $$\cos (180 - \theta) = -\cos \theta$$.

> $$OD^2+OA^2-2\cdot OD\cdot OA\cos 45 = AD^2$$
> $$OA^2+OB^2+2\cdot OA\cdot OB\cos 45 = AB^2$$
> $$OB^2+OC^2-2\cdot OB\cdot OC\cos 45 = BC^2$$
> $$OC^2+OD^2+2\cdot OC\cdot OD\cos 45 = CD^2$$

Obtain

$$4[ABCD] = -AD^2+AB^2-BC^2+CD^2$$

Comment: Great solution, took time to understand though. I doubt any easier solutions for this.

Comment: Might look straightforward for you, but not for me since I am not that familiar with trigonometry and mainly do not use it.

Comment: Taken trigonometry? I am in grade $8$ now, just a teenager :P .

Comment: Nice solution! and @Anonymous, you are in class 8? wow! Also which book are you doing these geo problems from ?

Comment: They are not from any book, my teacher has given me these problems.

Comment: @Anonymous, your teacher has wonderful collection of problems! And I commend you for being passionate in solving them! Maybe you can ask him to give your brief intro to trigo? :)

Comment: @cosmo5 thanks for the compliment !! and yes, I already have a brief intro to trig, I just need to practice right now to strengthen it, I feel a little short in cases where to use trig and where not to.

Comment: Also @cosmo5, did you mean $4[ABCD] = AB^2 + CD^2 - AD^2 - BC^2$ $?$ , I am having a bit confusion there.

Comment: Yes. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: Just saw this. Nice solution!

Comment: I think not learning trigo for a while is actually not a bad idea for strong foundation in geometry :) the moment you know trigo, you lose patience in finding a pure geometry solution quickly :)

Comment: @Anonymous Could have never thought you would be in class 8!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution without trigonometry. Drop altitudes DE and BF to the base AC, with E and F as the feet. The area is

\begin{align}
Area&= \frac12 AC \cdot ( DE + BF)\\
& =\frac12(AO \cdot ED +CO\cdot ED+AO\cdot BF + CO\cdot BF)\tag1
\end{align}

Per ED = EO, alone with the Pythagorean’s theorem
\begin{align}
2AO\cdot ED &= -(AO -EO)^2 +AO^2 +ED^2\\
&=-AE^2 +AO^2 +ED^2\\
&= -AD^2 +AO^2+ 2ED^2\\
\\
2 CO\cdot ED&= CD^2 -CO^2-2ED^2\\
2AO\cdot BF &= AB^2 -AO^2- 2BF^2 \\
2 CO\cdot BF&= CO^2-BC^2+2BF^2\\
\end{align}

Substitute above into (1) to obtain
$$Area= \frac{AB^2-AD^2-BC^2+CD^2}4$$

Comment: Nice! Same route but in OP's preference. +1