# Stuck in finding the area of a convex quad

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Problem:

A convex quadrilateral has sides $10$, $6$, $8$ and $2$ (in that order). If the angle between the diagonals is $π/4$, then find the area of the quadrilateral.

I tried applying the Law of Cosines for the angles in between the diagonals, but arrived at a weird relation.

[image]

Any hints?

PS: I don't know much Latex, so I had to use radians instead of degrees.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938632/a-quadrilateral-abcd-with-ab-10-bc-6-cd-8-and-da-2-has-dia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If distances from the intersection point of the diagonals to the vertices are $a, b, c, d$, here is the relations between them -

$a^2+b^2 - 2 ab \cos 135^0 = 64$

Please note the area of $\triangle AOB$ is $A_1 = \frac{1}{2} ab \sin 135^0 = - \frac{1}{2} ab \cos 135^0$

So, $a^2+b^2 + 4A_1 = 64$ ...(i)

Similarly, $c^2+d^2 + 4A_3 = 100$ ...(ii)

You also get,

$b^2+d^2 - 4A_2 = 36$ ...(iii)

$c^2+a^2 - 4A_4 = 4$ ...(iv)

Subtract (iii) from (i), (iv) from (ii) and then add. What do you get?

Comment: 31 if I calculated correctly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Is it also possible to calculate the individual areas?

Comment: For that we may have to find $a, b, c, d$. There are $4$ variables and $4$ equations so we can find but it will be more work as they are all quadratic.

Comment: @ MathLover: btw  how to label side lengths and angles in Geogebra drawing/construction?

Comment: @Narasimham it is under _Measure_ in Tools that appears on the left. Also if you select object say a line segment and go to settings, there are different ways to label it.

Comment: Thanks @ Math Lover, will find it out.